# jQuery click event fails on first attempt

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a function bound to my onClick for specific class.  The function doesn't seem to fire on the first attempt, but works fine after that.  The weird thing is that the alert I have in the script does work every time, so I cannot figure out why the rest of the function fails.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // capture original link and asset name on click
    $("a.dggate").bind("click", function () {
        window.tempURL = $("a.dggate").attr("href");
        window.assetTitle = $("a.dggate").attr("title");
        strAsset = assetTitle;
        alert("click " + knownUser);
        if (knownUser != true) {
            //alert(tempURL);
            $("a.dggate").fancybox({
                // choose which form to display
                href: "http://www.domain.com/",
                type: 'iframe',
                scrolling: 'no',
                width: "60%",
                height: "100%",
                titleShow: false
            });
        } else {
            // send blind form if user is known
            bFormSubmit();
            return false;
        }
    }); // click
}); // ready
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Trivial question, but is knownUser == true on the first click?

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but `$("a.dggate")` inside the handler should be `$(this)`. Otherwise, it applies to all members of the class, not just the one you clicked on (I'm assuming you're using a class because there can be more than one).

Comment: I think you misunderstand how to use FancyBox. Calling `fancybox()` on an element doesn't display the box, it just binds fancybox's click handler to the element. Then the next click runs fancybox's handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing

```
$("a.dggate").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

instead of that "bind" line, seems to work.

Comment: This solved the issue.  I think Barmar is right in the assignment of fancybox to the class, however, this function is really there to override the default which is the true href of the link, since its an external url and there are other times when it is inline with the page.  The click function seems to retain the original href, until the link is clicked a second time.  Thanks so much!